# When does SonarQube end an analysis database update?

Tags: sonarqube

During a CI process, after a SonarQube Scanner analysis, we must produce some reports using fresh analysis result data.

SonarQube stores analysis results data asynchronously but we have to know if a project has a store job queued, running or ended in order to proceed with our CI flow.

So the question is: is there a way to know if a SonarQube project data are really updated with last analysis results or if there is an update data process queued for that project ?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

From v5.2 the SonarQube server provides the web services you need. Check [Breaking the CI Build](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Breaking+the+CI+Build) for details. You don't want to break anything, but what you need is there.